# How to check if file is an element of arbitrarily deep folder tree in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I'm traversing a files tree in Python, and for EACH file I need to check whether that files tree contains file named the same as the original, but 'ca' is replaced with 'wpa'. E.g. for file 'ca123.txt' I would have to check if there exists file named 'wpa123.txt'.

The problem is that the result I get with the following code searches just on the level it currently stands on, not throughout the whole tree. How can I search the whole file tree from the current position?

```
import os

n=0
path=input()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.replace('ca','wpa') in files:
            n+=1
print(n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pathlib and glob instead of os.walk().

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path

n=0
path=Path(input())
files = [f.name for f in p.glob("**/*")]
for file in files:
    if 'ca' in file:
        if file.replace('ca','wpa') in files:
            n+=1
print(n)
```